# Swap neighboring elements grouped by two's [1,2,3,4,5,6] = [2,1,4,3,6,5]

Tags: java, arrays, swap

```
public static void swap(int [] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        int temp = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = array[i];
        array[i]=temp;
    }
}
```

I want to swap each neighboring element by twos. This code gives me `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]` instead of [`2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]`.

Comment: Isn't that quite easy to debug with pen and paper? The question doesn't seem to have a lot of effort behind it apparently

Comment: Every programming student, without exception, should learn to use a debugger as early as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just increment by 2, since you essentially want to swap every *other* pair of consecutive elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i += 2) {
                                    ^
```